# Подсветка javascript в Sublime Text

Tags: sublime-text

Подскажите, пожалуйста, цветовые схемы для Sublime Text, которые будут подсвечивать JS-код.
Ставил все плагины, у которых в названии есть JS, искал в интернете, но ничего дельного не нашёл.
На данный момент код подсвечивается не весь:

[image: Код JS]

Больше всего раздражает, что не подсвечиваются `this`, `length`и прочее, что часто используется.

Comment: Вы мне посоветовали тему оформления, в данной теме просто белый цвет заменет на голубой и наоборот

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На англоязычном Stack Overflow заплюсован [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18071378/5951529) о цветовой теме [Neon](https://github.com/MattDMo/Neon-color-scheme). По заверению разработчика в схеме поддерживаются Python, Ruby, Clojure, JavaScript/JSON, C/C++, diff, HTML/XML, Markdown, reStructuredText, PHP, CSS/SCSS/SASS, GitGutter, Find In Files, PackageDev, Regex и SublimeLinter.

Neon отличается огромным выбором настроек.

Monokai, установленная по умолчанию.

[image: Monokai]

Neon. Обращаем внимание на полосу прокрутки.

[image: Neon]

Результат для javascript:

[image: Neon javascript]

Если какой-то цвет не понравился, можно сменить его в GUI, [здесь](http://tmtheme-editor.herokuapp.com/#!/editor/theme/Neon).

В вопросе просили подсказать уже имеющиеся цветовые схемы, но можно и задать цвета неподсвечиваемым элементам кода [самостоятельно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/516668/199934).

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

**Дополнено**

Перебрал несколько плагинов, остановился на [Java​Script​Next - ES6 Syntax](https://web.archive.org/web/20181207194725/https://packagecontrol.io/packages/JavaScriptNext%20-%20ES6%20Syntax)

preferences - color theme - javascript next - две темы с подсветкой this.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
<sub>(источник: [packagecontrol.io](https://packagecontrol.io/readmes/img/99e3efd571ef62a2049377d61a93c2696dc7ba8a.png))</sub>

Comment: Да пожалуй это лучший из плагинов, но опять таки не подсвечивает ни `this`, ни `length`, хотя и подсвечивает многие стандартные методы

Comment: @PyMbIH что значит не подсвечиваются, вам нужен автокомплит кода?

Comment: @Jean-Claude, нет, ему нужно, чтобы `this` и `length` были раскрашенные, а не белые. Чтобы выделены были.

Comment: @PyMbIH добавил в ответ

Answer (score 1):

1. Как вариант, подходит [Babel](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Babel)-плагин (тут подсвечивается необходимый вам `this`):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. Довольно известный [JSHint](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/JSHint):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3. Можете также попробовать [JsFormat](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/JsFormat):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну а так - все находится по 1-й же ссылке [**по нормальному запросу**](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=sublime%20text%20javascript%20plugin).

Comment: Скриншот, который я приложил, это код, с установленым в настройках "View -> Syntax -> Babel -> JavaScript(Babel), JsFormat - в установках синтаксиса вовсе нет, впрочем как JsHint

Comment: @PyMbIH мы не гадалки и не можем знать, что у вас установлено уже, а что - нет. Описывайте свой вопрос полностью.

Comment: @Denis JSHint и JsFormat это же не плагины подсветки кода, а форматтеры-бьютиферы. Написано `JsFormat is a javascript formatting plugin. It uses jsbeautifier`.

Answer (score 1):

Плагин [JavaScript Ultimate](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/JavaScript%20Ultimate), имеет настройку синтаксиса `JavaScript Ultimate -> JavaScript(DOM)`, `this`, правда не подсвечивает, но все остальное на ура

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также при выборе цветовой схемы, подсвечивается и `this`

Comment: Пожалуйста, отметьте подошедшее Вам решение галочкой.