# Смена визуальных характеристик элементов готового синтаксиса в Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublime-text, sublime-text-3

Не подсвечиваются/выделяются фоном нужные мне элементы кода.

[image: JavaScript с неподсвеченными элементами]

Сколько цветовых схем не перепробовал — ничего не помогает. Как написать простейший собственный синтаксис, расписано [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/503513/199934), но что нужно проделать для изменения уже готовых?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если не устраивает ни одна готовая схема, задаём цвета самостоятельно. Стоит предупредить о трёх обстоятельствах:

1. С момента внесения правки в цветовую схему до отображения нового цвета может пройти несколько минут. Иногда помогает перезагрузка файла или самого Sublime Text 3.
2. Из stack trace и всплывающих окон редактора не всегда понятно, где совершил опечатку в синтаксисе. Рекомендую пользоваться плагином [Local History](https://github.com/vishr/local-history), чтобы оставалась возможность откатиться до предыдущих версий файла.
3. Scopes (см. ниже) меняются с выходом новых билдов Sublime Text 3. После обновления может оказаться, что прописанные вами настройки сбились, и придётся заново вставлять уже новые области видимости.

Свойства, отвечающие за цвет и начертание элементов синтаксиса языков разметки, программирования, наборов макропакетов, языков и таблиц стилей и т. д. в Sublime Text 3 называются «scopes». Перевёл как «области видимости», за точность перевода не ручаюсь.

**Куда что вставлять**

1. Открываем файл своей активной цветовой темы (схемы). Если не знаете, как, см. [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/516033/199934) в первых двух абзацах после «Простое решение».
2. Куда-нибудь между тегами `<array></array>` нашей цветовой схемы вносим следующий XML-массив:

   ```
   <!-- Комментарий -->
   <dict>
       <key>name</key>
       <string>Scope Name</string>
       <key>scope</key>
       <string>scope(s)</string>
       <key>settings</key>
       <dict>
           <key>foreground</key>
           <string>color</string>
       </dict>
   </dict>
   ```

   Параметры:

   `<!-- Комментарий -->` — необязательный. Дабы не забыть, что означает вставленная нами область видимости.

   `<key>name</key>`, `<string>Scope Name</string>` — необязательный. Между тегами `<string></string>` задаём любое имя области видимости, которое будет отображаться в [TmTheme Editor](https://tmtheme-editor.herokuapp.com).

   `<key>scope</key>`, `<string>scope(s)</string>` — между тегами `<string></string>` вставляем область (или области) видимости. Как их получить — см. ниже по тексту. Важно не оставлять пространство между `<string></string>` пустым, — иначе цветом, что указан у вас вместо `color`, подсветится и совсем не то, что вы хотели.

   `<key>foreground</key>`, `<string>color</string>` — между тегами `<string></string>` указываем цвет в форматах [HEX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors#Hex_triplet), [ARGB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGBA_color_space#ARGB_.28word-order.29) или [X11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors#X11_color_names). Последний формат не рекомендовал бы ввиду того, что *а)* как минимум цвета `aqua`, `fuchsia` и `lime` не всегда поддерживаются Sublime Text 3, *б)* периодически возникают разного рода неисправности, не случающиеся, если вводим цвет в HEX или ARGB.
3. Получаем и вносим область видимости одним из трёх способов, подробно расписанных ниже, вслед за примерами.
4. Вписываем в XML-конструкцию цвет вместо `color` → сохраняем файл цветовой схемы → смотрим результаты.

#### Примеры

*Золотой текст:*

```
<dict>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>text.html.basic source.js.embedded.html source.js meta.group.braces.round meta.group.braces.curly meta.property.object.js </string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>foreground</key>
        <string>gold</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

[image: Золотой текст]

*Зелёный фон:*

```
<dict>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>text.html.basic source.js.embedded.html source.js meta.group.braces.round meta.group.braces.curly meta.function-call.method.without-arguments.js variable.function.js </string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>background</key>
        <string>#6BC7548F</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

[image: Золотой текст]

*Наклонный коралловый текст:*

```
<dict>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>text.html.basic source.js.embedded.html source.js meta.group.braces.round meta.group.braces.curly meta.function-call.method.with-arguments.js variable.function.js </string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>fontStyle</key>
        <string>italic</string>
        <key>foreground</key>
        <string>lightcoral</string>
    </dict>
```

[image: Наклонный коралловый текст]

Ключи `foreground`, `fontStyle` (принимает значения `bold` или `italic`, значения указывать со строчной буквы) и `background` можно комбинировать между собой, т. е. допускается одновременное задание цвета элемента, его начертания и цвета фона вокруг:

```
<dict>
    <key>fontStyle</key>
    <string>italic</string>
    <key>foreground</key>
    <string>lightcoral</string>
</dict>
```

Несколько областей видимости, которые будут иметь одинаковый цвет, вносятся через запятую. Допустим, мы желаем идентичную раскраску у открывающих и закрывающих скобок тега `<script></script>`:

```
<!-- HTML: угловые скобки тега <script>, открывающие и закрывающие -->
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Tag script brackets, open and closed</string>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>text.html.basic source.js.embedded.html punctuation.definition.tag.begin.html, text.html.basic source.js.embedded.html punctuation.definition.tag.end.html  </string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>foreground</key>
        <string>yellow</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

[image: Открывающие и закрывающие скобки тега script]

Результат, после того, как мы задали цвета областям видимости всем элементам примера.

*Было*:

[image: Было]

*Стало*:

[image: Стало]

**Получение областей видимости**:

Узнать активную, т. е. до или в пределах которой находится каретка, область видимости элемента можно сочетанием клавиш <kbd>Ctrl + Alt + Shift+ P</kbd>. Scope отобразится в строке состояния (Status Bar) нижней части окна Sublime Text 3.

[image: Область видимости в строке состояния]

Однако из строки состояния не скопировать необходимую область видимости, необходимо воспользоваться одним из трёх способов ниже. Плагины от [adzenith](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/how-to-copy-the-scope/1259) и [ttscoff](https://gist.github.com/ttscoff/2721811), также предназначенные для получения scopes в буфер обмена, у меня не заработали, — по всей видимости, они для Sublime Text 2, но не Sublime Text 3.

**UPD:**
Начиная с билда 3114 области видимости отображаются уже в отдельном окне, а не строке состояния, и их можно копировать.

[image: Scopes in Build 3114]

Плагин от r-stein, о котором идёт речь ниже, уже не особо и нужен.

**1. Плагин от [r-stein](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5963435/r-stein)**

Проделаем следующие операции:

*а*. Копируем в буфер обмена следующий код:

> `sublime.set_clipboard(view.scope_name(view.sel()[0].b))`

*б*. Устанавливаем каретку (упрощённо говоря, кликаем левой кнопкой мыши) до или внутри — но не после — элемента синтаксиса, цвет которого хотим изменить.

*в*. <kbd>Ctrl + `</kbd> (машинописный обратный апостроф, символ расположен на той же клавише, где кириллическая «ё») → вставляем в открывшееся поле ввода код, что мы скопировали на 1-м этапе, → <kbd>Enter</kbd> → в нашем буфере обмена содержится необходимая область видимости.

Как можно убедиться на практике, это не очень удобно. Для упрощения выполнения операции служит плагин от ув-мого r-stein.

1. <kbd>Tools</kbd> → <kbd>New plugin...</kbd> → Вставляем в открывшийся файл код на Python:

> import sublime, sublime_plugin
>
> class CopyScopeCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
>          def run(self, edit):
>              view = self.view
>              sublime.set_clipboard(view.scope_name(view.sel()[0].b))
>              sublime.status_message("Scope copied")

<kbd>Ctrl + S</kbd> → сохраняем файл как `copy_scope.py`.

2. Задаём плагину шорткат: <kbd>Preferences</kbd> → <kbd>Paskage Settings</kbd> → <kbd>Mediawiker</kbd> → <kbd>Key Bindings - User</kbd> → между `[]` вписываем в открывшийся файл:

   ```
    // Копирование областей видимости
   { "keys": ["ctrl+7", "ctrl+o"], "command": "copy_scope" },
   ```

Сохраняем. Чтобы сочетание наверняка оказалось ничем не занятым, я выбираю двухэтапные хоткеи — то есть ввожу <kbd>Ctrl + 7</kbd>, затем <kbd>Ctrl + O</kbd>, и только после двух нажатий выполняется необходимая команда. Можете назначить одноэтапный, только лучше удостоверьтесь, что шорткат свободен: <kbd>Preferences</kbd> → <kbd>Key Bindings - Default</kbd> → в открывшемся файле <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> → временно отключаем кнопку <kbd>Regular expression</kbd>, иначе не удастся найти символ `+`, → вводим в форму поиска сочетание клавиш, которое хотим использовать, → если оно задействовано, выбираем другое, которое, впрочем, также может быть занято каким-то из установленных вами плагинов.

3. (опционально) Добавляем кнопку вызова плагина в контекстное меню, появляющееся при нажатии правой кнопкой мыши в любую область ввода текста:

[image: Copy_scope в контекстном меню]

<kbd>Preferences</kbd> → <kbd>Browse Packages...</kbd> → <kbd>User</kbd> → создаём файл **Context.sublime-menu**, если его нет, → вставляем в файл

```
[
    {
        "command": "copy_scope"
    },
]
```

Сохраняем. Если же файл существует, и в нём прописана команда для другого плагина, разделяем объекты запятыми после {фигурных скобок}. Объекты заключены в [квадратные скобки] ([JSON-синтаксис](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=28&id=702)).

```
[
    {
        "command": "lat_to_cyr"
    },
    {
        "command": "copy_scope"
    },
]
```

То же замечание по поводу запятых и скобок касается предыдущего и последующего примеров.

4. (опционально) Добавляем кнопку вызова плагина в верхнее меню:

[image: Copy_scope в верхнем меню]

<kbd>Preferences</kbd> → <kbd>Browse Packages...</kbd> → <kbd>User</kbd> → создаём файл **Main.sublime-menu**, если его нет, → вписываем:

```
[
{
        "id": "edit",
        "children":
        [
            { "command": "copy_scope" }
        ]
    },
]
```

Сохраняем.

5. Наводим каретку до или внутри элемента, область видимости которого следует узнать, → вызываем команду получения scope любым из методов — <kbd>Ctrl + 7</kbd>, затем <kbd>Ctrl + O</kbd>; клик правой кнопкой мыши в любую область ввода текста → <kbd>Copy Scope</kbd>; <kbd>Edit</kbd> → <kbd>Copy Scope</kbd> — область видимости находится в нашем буфере обмена.

**2. ScopeHunter онлайн**

Сервис поддерживает только синтаксисы, перечисленные на картинке ниже,

[image: Языки ScopeHunter]

тогда как методами 1 и 3 изменяется раскраска у любых элементов всех синтаксисов Sublime Text 3. Например, я написал цветовую схему с поддержкой [вики-разметки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0), для меня вариант со ScopeHunter онлайн частично не подошёл.

Переходим на [сайт TmTheme Editor](https://tmtheme-editor.herokuapp.com) → <kbd>Gallery</kbd>, если пользуетесь готовой цветовой схемой, <kbd>Open</kbd> — собственной (когда файл темы находится среди файлов вашего компьютера, открываете его, как описано [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/516033/199934), и в `title` окна Sublime Text 3 высветится путь к локальному файлу) → в правом нижнем углу выбираем необходимый язык разметки/программирования → <kbd>Customize Preview Code</kbd> → вставляем тот самый код, где элементы подсвечиваются не так, как вам нужно → <kbd>Save</kbd> → <kbd>Scope Hunter</kbd> → наводим мышью на элементы → под строкой <kbd>Current Scope</kbd> выводится искомая область видимости:

[image: Скрин с курсором]

Если у выбранной области видимости задан параметр «Name» (под «Matching Rule»), то слева находим Score Name c таким же значением параметра, как у «Name», → меняем цвета в веб-панели. Доступен онлайн-предпросмотр.

Когда же напротив Name ничего не указано, придётся создавать XML-массив (см. **Куда что вставлять**) и вписывать область видимости в него.

<kbd>Save</kbd> → <kbd>Download</kbd> → сохраняем файл туда же, откуда его взяли.

К сожалению, работа над сервисом [фактически прекращена](https://github.com/aziz/tmTheme-Editor/issues/213), результат будет отличаться от того, что вы имеете в Sublime Text 3, иногда разительно. Скриншоты одного скрипта, сделанные 13 июня 2016 в Sublime Text 3 и TmTheme Editor:

[image: ST3 screen]
[image: Heroku screen]

**3. Плагин ScopeHunter**

Поддерживаются любые синтаксисы. [Устанавливаем](https://github.com/facelessuser/ScopeHunter) плагин через [Package Control](http://forum.sublimetext.ru/index.php?topic=6.0) → <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + P</kbd> → в появившееся поле ввода вписываем одну из двух [команд](http://facelessuser.github.io/ScopeHunter/usage/#command-usage):

`Scope Hunter: Toggle Instant Scoper` — (зная о [fuzzy поиске](https://habrahabr.ru/post/147856/), можно ввести `shtis`) решение, когда необходимо изменить цвета множеству элементов. Внизу появится консоль, где отобразятся области видимости, автоматически сменяющиеся в зависимости от того, до или внутри какого элемента синтаксиса располагается каретка.

[image: Scopes в Output Console]

Чтобы scopes добавлялись в буфер обмена автоматически, задайте [значение *true* параметру *clipboard*](http://facelessuser.github.io/ScopeHunter/usage/#clipboard): <kbd>Preferences</kbd> → <kbd>Package Settings</kbd> → <kbd>ScopeHunter</kbd> → <kbd>Settings - User</kbd> → вставляем следующий код и сохраняем файл.

```
{
    "clipboard": true,
}
```

Когда вы не собираетесь работать с областями видимости, чтобы они не мешались в буфере обмена, установите значение *false* или же прекратите действие команды ScopeHunter перезагрузкой Sublime Text 3. Впрочем, иногда она сама по непонятным причинам прекращает функционировать, и приходится заново после <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+P</kbd> вводить `shtis`.

`Scope Hunter: Show Scope Under Cursor` — подходит, когда требуется преобразить колор одному или нескольким элементам. После того, как вы закрываете консоль клавишей <kbd>Esc</kbd>, чтобы узнать области видимости ещё раз, придётся вновь набирать данную команду.

Если в течение сеанса работы в Sublime Text 3 вы ввели одну из этих команд, то другая не заработает до того, как вы перезагрузите Sublime Text 3.

Поддерживаются множественные курсоры. Зажмите клавишу <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> и кликайте мышью до или внутри элементов, область видимости которых необходимо узнать. В нижней консоли появятся scopes сразу всех их. Пример:

```
Scope:                         text.html.basic
                               source.js.embedded.html
                               source.js
                               meta.group.braces.round
                               meta.brace.round.js
------
Scope:                         text.html.basic
                               source.js.embedded.html
                               source.js
                               meta.group.braces.round
                               meta.group.braces.curly
                               variable.other.readwrite.js
------
Scope:                         text.html.basic
                               source.js.embedded.html
                               source.js
                               meta.group.braces.round
                               meta.group.braces.curly
                               support.type.object.dom.js
------
```

Копируем области видимости (то, что справа, без `Scope:` с чёрточками).

**Резюме**

по рассмотренным способам получения областей видимости:

1. `Плагин от r-stein:`
   *Плюс* — наиболее быстрое получение scopes,
   *Минус* — нет никаких дополнительных функций.
2. `ScopeHunter онлайн:`
   *Плюс* — быстрый предпросмотр цветов онлайн,
   *Минусы* — неактивный разработчик и как следствие отсутствие поддержки новых изменений; ограниченная поддержка синтаксисов.
3. `Плагин ScopeHunter:`
   *Плюс* — работа сразу с множеством областей видимости,
   *Минус* — перебои в работе плагина.

Когда мне требуется изменить 1—2 области видимости, я пользуюсь плагином от r-stein; нужен быстрый предпросмотр — захожу в TmThemeEditor; ну а если основательно сажусь править цветовых темы, то привожу в действие плагин ScopeHunter.

[image: Спасибо за внимание!]