# Как узнать поддерживается ли html тег в определенной версии браузера?

Tags: html, браузер, кроссбраузерность, спецификация

Хочу узнать, какие теги поддерживаются в старых браузерах. Например, взять теги small, big bgsound и другие. Хочу узнать с какой версии браузеров они начинают поддерживаться (mozilla, ie, chrome, safari, opera)? Есть ли где-нибудь официальная информация? Или даже если не официальная, но та, которая соответствует действительности, может сервис какой? Т.к. в интернете на разных сайтах информация разнится касаемо поддержки в разных версиях браузеров

Answer (score 6):

Проверяю на сайте [**webref.ru**](https://webref.ru). Нужно ввести тег/элемент синтаксиса CSS в соответствующую форму, и не требуется дополнительно жать на <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

1. Материалы сайта [**написаны квалифицированными профессионалами**](https://webref.ru/author). Главный редактор — «веб-разработчик, автор нескольких книг, посвящённых созданию сайтов, HTML и CSS. Кандидат технических наук.»
2. Русский язык.
3. Частые обновления информации. На страницах указывается дата обновлений.
4. Указывается статус в [**спецификациях**](http://www.webnav.ru/books/html4/html_rules/#3):

[image: Спецификация тега]

А если тег в них не входит, как в Вашем случае с `<bgsound>`, приводится следующее сообщение:

[image: Тег не входит в спецификацию]

5. Дополнительная информация о тегах/элементах синтаксиса CSS.
6. Если что-то осталось неясным, возможность оставлять комментарии, на которые есть шанс получить квалифицированный ответ.

---

---

Если Вы верстаете сайты в Sublime Text, для ускорения работы можно воспользоваться плагином [**FindDoc**](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/FindDoc). Выделяете необходимый элемент синтаксиса HTML/CSS → нажимаете заданное сочетание → получаете результат в браузере.

[image: **FindDoc**]

Необходимо настроить плагин на Webref. `Preferences` → `Key Bindings` → в правую pane вставляете следующий код:

```
// FindDoc Webref
{
    "keys": ["ctrl+alt+keypad9"],
    "command": "find_doc_selection",
    "args" : {"url" : "https://webref.ru/html/%s#field_html_browser"},
    "context": [
        {
            "key":      "selector",
            "operand":  "text.html.basic"
        }
    ]
},
// FindDoc Webref
{
    "keys": ["ctrl+alt+keypad9"],
    "command": "find_doc_selection",
    "args" : {"url" : "https://webref.ru/css/%s#field_css_browser"},
    "context": [
        {
            "key":      "selector",
            "operand":  "source.css"
        }
    ]
},
```

Параметры:

`"keys"` — ваш шорткат, выбираете произвольный, незанятый.
`"command": "find_doc_selection"` — запуск FindDoc.
`url" : "https://webref.ru/html/%s#field_html_browser",` — URL, который откроется в браузере по умолчанию. `%s` — переменная, вместо неё подставится то, что мы выделили. В примере было выделено `text-align`, значит, откроется https://webref.ru/css/text-align#field_css_browser. Если [**предпочитаете Can I use**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/514910/199934), значение параметра URL будет следующим: http://caniuse.com/#search=%s.
`"key": "selector"` — аргумент означает, что команда будет работать только в файлах, имеющих область видимости, назначенную в параметре `"operand"`.
`"operand": "source.css"` — [**область видимости**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/516668/199934). `text.html.basic` для HTML и `source.css`. Если мы запустим команду в HTML-файле, откроется ссылка, прописанная для HTML, в CSS-файле ссылка для CSS.

Если мы нажмём <kbd>Сtrl+Alt+Keypad9</kbd>, например, в `js`-файле, то в браузере ничего не откроется, поскольку аргументами мы ограничили действие команды `find_doc_selection` `html` и `css` файлами. Однако по тому же образцу можно настроить для области видимости JavaScript — `source.js` — открытие ссылки на [**JavaScript.ru**](http://javascript.ru/manual) или другом сайте.

Comment: хотя насчет webref не соглашусь, там куча ошибок

Comment: Повнимательнее изучил сайт webref. Скажу честно, сайт полная лажа, абсолютно не соответствует стандарту html. А из того, что есть, информация зачастую подается без понимания смысла автором того, что он пишет. Складывается ощущение, что он совершенно не понимает, как работают некоторые теги, а тупо копирует контент с других сайтов, делая небольшой рерайт. А описание некоторых элементов информация вообще соответствует действительности.

Comment: @ПавелИгорев, примеры, подтверждающие Ваши утверждения, могли бы привести? Спасибо.

Comment: Просто для примера, взять элемент <input>, отсутствуют атрибуты height, inputmode, width, также отсутствует указание на то, что атрибут pattern имеет нестандартную семантику.

Comment: Еще, например, элемент <link>. Отсутствуют атрибуты crossorigin, rev, hreflang, также отсутствует указание на то, что атрибут pattern имеет нестандартную семантику. Когда описывается атрибут media элемента <link>, так называемый автор указывает в значениях 4 типа (хотя в стандарте их больше, 4 это в неутвержденном), а ниже пишет, что в качестве значений могут быть указаны медиа-запросы. Хотя типы - это и есть часть меди-запросов. И таких куча примеров.

Answer (score 3):

1. [http://caniuse.com/](http://caniuse.com/#) - вводите название тега/css фичи и смотрите
2. https://modernizr.com/ - позволяет силами JS в рантайме
   определять поддержку элемента в текущем окружении

Answer (score 1):

Кроме всего прочего, никогда не помешает зайти на [W3C](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/bgsound) - тех, кто занимается спецификацией тегов непосредственно. Там всегда можно найти свежую информацию касательно новых и старых тегов и их применения.

В частности, по вашему вопросу о `bgsound` они пишут следующее:

> No, really. Don't use it.

И варианты альтернатив приводят, если таковые есть и необходимы.