# Иконки файлов в сайдбаре Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublime-text, sublime-text-3

Установил новую тему для `Sublime Text 3` только ради иконок файлов в `Sidebar`. Но на деле оказалось всё не так радужно.
Как должно быть:

[image: Как должно быть]

Как у меня:

[image: Как у меня]

Да и иконка `.sass` не та:

[image: sass]

То есть `Sublime Text` не понимает эти типы файлов. И во всех темах есть этот косяк. Главный трабл в том что я специально скачал чистую `portable` версию, и даже в ней не работает. Да и вообще есть несоответствия с многими иконками. В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Есть подозрение, что он берет дефолтные настройки самой операционной системы  для файлов, а не достает их из коробки плагина. А вообще даже не понятно, что это за тема и откуда вы ее взяли.

Comment: Это Material Theme, Довольно популярная. А также использовал тему Cyanide, и в ней те же самые проблемы, с теми самыми же типами файлов. Так что скорее всего да, это как-то связано с настройками операционной системой. Мда..

Comment: Очень похожа на мою Spacegray, только с иконками проблем нет у нее. Попробуй ее поставить и посмотреть. Скорее всего в теме дело. + еще ведь есть расширение конкретно для иконок, нет? По-моему есть, поищи.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Во-первых, [скачаем](https://github.com/equinusocio/material-theme/archive/develop.zip) выбранную Вами Material Theme, перейдём в папку `icons` и посмотрим, какая иконка соответствует JavaScript.

[image: JS icon]

Такая, как на Вашем скриншоте. В истории коммитов копаться неохота, однако предположу, что девелоперы сменили иконку, забыв отразить это в скриншотах на заглавной.

Если Вам не нравятся предлагаемые разработчиками тем, можете установить вручную в качестве иконки для используемых Вами языков программирования/разметки и прочих файлов любое изображение.

Для начала переместим требуемые изображения в какую-нибудь папку. Ссылки на некоторые наборы иконок выложены в [данном](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/sidebar-icons-in-themes/13119) треде на форуме Sublime Text, мы воспользуемся файлами из `Material Theme`, пусть для `Sass` там выбрана на мой взгляд неудачная иконка. `Preferences` → `Browse Paskages...` → `User`. Создаём папку `Theme - Default`, если она ещё не создана. Название для папки не я придумал, оно обычно используется. Копируем туда всё — или только изображения, которые пригодятся, — из папки `icons` Material Theme.

`Preferences` → `Browse Paskages...` → `User` → `Theme - Default` → создаём папку `Preferences`, в которой будут располагаться файлы, о которых зайдёт речь ниже. В один всё у меня вместить не получается, придётся с каждой иконкой связывать отдельный файл с расширением `tmPreferences`.

#### Ruby

В новый файл `Ruby.tmPreferences` вставляем XML-конструкцию ниже, и сохраняем его:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>source.ruby</string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>icon</key>
        <string>Theme - Default/file_type_ruby</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Между вторыми тегами `<string></string>` указывается путь к файлу иконки и его имя без расширения.

#### Sass

Предположу, что Вы получили неудовлетворительные результаты, поскольку не подключили отсутствующий по умолчанию в сборке Sublime Text 3 синтаксис Sass. Через [Package Control](http://forum.sublimetext.ru/index.php?topic=6.0) устанавливаем [плагин](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Syntax%20Highlighting%20for%20Sass), который в Package Control (имена плагинов в репозиториях, на сайте Package Control и самом Package Control могут отличаться) называется просто `Sass`.

Теперь можно связывать `sass`-файлы с иконками. Создаём файл `Sass.tmPreferences` и вставляем в него код.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>source.sass</string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>icon</key>
        <string>Theme - Default/file_type_sass</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

#### Markdown

Здесь между первыми тегами `<string></string>` недостаточно по аналогии вписать `source.markdown` или `source.md`, и такое может случиться для других языков разметки/программирования. Потребуется вставить «область видимости», scope. Как её получить, я очень подробно расписал в [данном](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/516668/199934) ответе. Итак, достаём область видимости:

[image: Markdown scope]

Сколько бы записей в ней не содержалось, нас интересует только первая, `text.html.markdown.gfm`, которую мы и вставляем в файл `Markdown.tmPreferences`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>text.html.markdown.gfm</string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>icon</key>
        <string>Theme - Default/file_type_markdown</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Чтобы не вставлять код каждый раз вручную, рекомендую [скачать](https://jumpshare.com/v/hbKNi0rrClcPimWX6nDF?b=7rjaNxtnk0eyJhPpFxgP) набор из 70 `tm.Preferences` файлов для распространённых [компьютерных языков](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_language).

#### Изображения

К примеру, у бинарных, исполняемых файлов или картинок области видимости посмотреть не получится. Чтобы изменить им иконки, необходимо добавить файлы со следующими названиями в папку, где лежит файл активной темы с расширением `tmTheme`, у меня он располагается по пути `Preferences` → `Browse Paskages...` → `User`.

```
file_type_binary.png
file_type_default.png
file_type_image.png
file_type_markup.png
file_type_source.png
file_type_text.png
```

Из названий понятно для чего они предназначены. Напротив наших изображений теперь будет стоять иконка с названием `file_type_image.png`

Если сделали всё по данной инструкции, у файлов с соответствующими расширениями в сайдбаре должны появиться вот такие иконки.

[image: Custom sidebar icons]

Буквально во всех темах, которые мне доводилось увидеть, за редким исключением используются одни и те же иконки. В светлых темах многие из них плохо видны, допустим, тот же оранжевый значок `JS` на жёлтом фоне.

[image: JS in light theme]

А иконки, взятые со сторонних сайтов, выглядят не очень красиво. Легко сменить цвета самому можно, например, в GIMP при помощи функции [Hue-Saturation](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tool-hue-saturation.html). Открываем в этом графическом редакторе файл иконки → `Tools` → `Color Tools` → `Hue-Saturation`, и двигаем слайдеры, — изменение цвета достигается перемещением ползунка `Hue`:

[image: Hue Saturation]

После того, как подобрали колор, яркость и насыщенность, `File` → `Overwrite file_type_%Ваш тип файла%.png`.

Примеры изменённых мной таким образом иконок:

```
file_type_js.png
file_type_markdown.png
file_type_source.png
file_type_yaml.png
```

[image: JS new icon]
[image: Markdown new icon]
[image: Source new icon]
[image: YAML new icon]

#### Возможные баги

Если вы скачали новую тему или схему, вне зависимости от того, будете ли использовать её или нет, иконки в сайдбаре могут пропасть. В консоли при этом выдаётся примерно следующая ошибка:

```
Errors parsing theme:
Rule is missing a class name
Unable to decode Packages/User/Theme - Default/arrow_down_over.png
pre session restore time: 0.3078
```

Устраняется проблема в 2 шага:

1. <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+P</kbd> → `Package Control: Remove Package` → выбираем нашу тему/цветовую схему и удаляем её. Можно сообщить о проблеме разработчику темы/схемы.
2. У меня портились файлы с расширением `tm.Preferences`, о которых говорилось выше. Вместо `icons/file_type_ruby` появлялись кракозябры.

[image: Кракозябры]

Откройте любой `tm.Preferences` файл, посмотрите, есть ли там какие-то кракозябры, и если да, то сделайте массовую замену кракозябр на корректные символы в папке, где хранятся `tm.Preferences` файлы, с помощью [поиска](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14108774/5951529) <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+F</kbd>.

После данных действий иконки вновь появлялись в моём сайдбаре.

Comment: Хороший мануал, спасибо

Answer (score 2):

На момент написания ответа проблема решается следующим образом:

- запускаем `Package Control: Install package` (комбинация клавиш `Ctrl+Shift+P`)
- вводим `A File Icon` в поисковую строку и устанавливаем
- перезапускаем Sublime Text 3 и иконки автоматически подтягиваются

[image: a file icon]

Исходники лежат по ссылке: [A File Icon](https://github.com/ihodev/a-file-icon)