# Как сделать вывод результатов компиляции PHP в новую вкладку Sublime Text?

Tags: php, sublime-text, sublime-text-3

Я смотрел разные мануалы, как запустить код PHP в Sublime Text, но в этих инструкциях результат всегда выводится в небольшую консольку самого Sublime Text. А могу ли я сделать «вывод в файл»? То есть чтобы при запуске кода открывалась новая вкладка, куда выводится результат запуска.

Comment: [**Terminality**](https://github.com/spywhere/Terminality)

Comment: @СашаЧерных, я посмотрел, этот плагин не поддерживает php.

Comment: Необходимо самому добавить. Уже пишу ответ, потерпите немножко.

Answer (score 1):

### Установка

#### Обязательно

- [**PHP**](https://secure.php.net/downloads.php). Если Вы пользуетесь [**Chocolatey**](https://chocolatey.org/), запустите в терминале команду `cinst php -y`.
- [**Terminality**](https://github.com/spywhere/Terminality). Плагин, с помощью которого решается данный вопрос.

#### Опционально

Плагины, чтобы не править конфигурационные файлы вручную. Дальнейшие действия в моём ответе подразумевают, что они установлены.

- [**Preferences Editor**](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Preferences%20Editor),
- [**Keymap Redefiner**](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Keymap%20Redefiner). (**WARNING!** Плагин удаляет комментарии из файла `.sublime-keymap` . Если они вам нужны, не пользуйтесь данным плагином.) Увы, но другого решения, чтобы не лезть в кеймап вручную, похоже, нет.

---

---

### Настройка Terminality для PHP

<kbd>Ctrl+Shift+P</kbd> → `Edit Preferences: Edit Settings...` → `Terminality` → `execution_units` → вставляем такой код:

```json
{"source.php": {"run": {"command": "php $file"}}}
```

→ <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

#### Параметры

`command: php $file` — запуск компилирования для файла в открытой вкладке.
`source.php` — [**область видимости**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/516668/199934) для синтаксиса PHP в Sublime Text.

---

---

### Назначение горячих клавиш

Если у Вас, как у меня, дефолтное сочетание <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+P</kbd> забито другим плагином, поменяйте его. <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+P</kbd> → `Keymap Redefiner: Define Keymap` → `Terminality` <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+R</kbd> (в Windows; есть ещё <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+Shift+R</kbd> для запуска команды с [**аргументами**](https://github.com/spywhere/Terminality#language-scopes)) → меняем хоткей на свободный. Чтобы хоткей наверняка не был ничем занят, биндим клавишу [**цифровой клавиатуры**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A6%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0), например, <kbd>super+keypad_multiply</kbd>. `keypad_multiply` — клавиша `*` над девяткой в Numpad. Жмём <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

---

---

### Результат

Создаём любой файл с расширением `php` → пишем «Hello World» или любой другой простой код → сохраняем файл → запускаем команду Terminality шорткатом, который мы только что задали. Должно получиться вот так.

[image: **Вывод PHP-кода в новую вкладку**]

Как и в стандартном для Sublime Text выводе через output console указывается время, потраченное на компиляцию, но уже в Title Bar и вкладке, в сантисекундах.

---

---

Для ознакомления с прочими возможностями и настройками Terminality читайте [**README.MD**](https://github.com/spywhere/Terminality) в репозитории данного плагина на GitHub.